# Unit of return value of ST_Distance

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I need to calculate the distance between

1. all buildings and
2. all hospitals

in a map imported from OSM.

I use following query:

```
SELECT building_id, hospital_id, ST_Distance(building_centroid, hospital_location)
FROM 
(
select planet_osm_polygon.osm_id building_id, ST_Centroid(planet_osm_polygon.way) building_centroid
from planet_osm_polygon
where building = 'yes'
) buildings,
(
select planet_osm_point.osm_id hospital_id, planet_osm_point.way hospital_location
from planet_osm_point  
where amenity = 'hospital') hospitals
```

I get strange results - the distance is always smaller than 1.

How can I get the to know the unit, in which these values are reported?

**Update 1:** Sample result:

[image: Sample result of the query above]

**Update 2:** This query seems to work

```
SELECT building_id, hospital_id, ST_Distance_sphere(building_centroid, hospital_location) distance
FROM 
(
select planet_osm_polygon.osm_id building_id, ST_Centroid(planet_osm_polygon.way)  building_centroid
from planet_osm_polygon
where building = 'yes'
) buildings,
(
select planet_osm_point.osm_id hospital_id, planet_osm_point.way hospital_location
from planet_osm_point  
where amenity = 'hospital') hospitals
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Please post a couple of relevant records from your tables.

Comment: thanks. Could you please also paste a couple of records from `planet_osm_polygon` and `planet_osm_point`, those with ids returned by your query? Please also post definitions of your tables (`CREATE TABLE ...`)

Comment: @Quassnoi Table definitions can be found here - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_11_05_postgis/table_defs.sql

Comment: @Quassnoi Contents of the table `planet_osm_polygon` - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_11_05_postgis/planet_osm_polygon.csv

Comment: @Quassnoi Contents of the table `planet_osm_point` - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_11_05_postgis/planet_osm_point.csv

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The general rule for units is that the output length units are the same as the input length units.

The OSM `way` geometry data has length units of degrees of latitude and longitude ([`SRID=4326`](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)). Therefore, the output units from [ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) will also have lenth units of degrees, which are not really useful.

There are several things you can do:

- Use [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) for fast/approximate distances in metres
- Use [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) for accurace distances in metres
- Convert the lat/long `geometry` data types to `geography`, which automagically makes ST_Distance and other functions to use linear units of metres